# Returning Element Values by Attribute Using C# and Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm VERY new to using LINQ.  I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <RetentionValue code="NR" fullName="Normal Retention">Used for normal retention periods commonly expressed as only numbers (i.e. "25" for 25 years).</RetentionValue>
  <RetentionValue code="SR" fullName="Short Retention">Used for short retention periods expressed in terms of months (i.e. "6 months").</RetentionValue>
  <RetentionValue code="AR" fullName="Annual Review">Review annually and retain what is needed, dispose of what is not needed.</RetentionValue>
  <RetentionValue code="PE" fullName="Permanent">Document is to be retained permanently.</RetentionValue>
  <RetentionValue code="EX" fullName="Expiration">Disposal date is calculated from expiration of a contract, loan, or other such instrument.</RetentionValue>
  <RetentionValue code="LI" fullName="Lifetime">Disposal date is calculated from the end-of-life date for a piece of equipment or other asset (e.g. software application).</RetentionValue>
  <RetentionValue code="TE" fullName="Employee Termination">Disposal date is calculated from the date of termination or retirement of an employee.</RetentionValue>
  <RetentionValue code="FR" fullName="Final Resolution">Disposal date is calculated from the date of final resolution for an issue.</RetentionValue>
</root>
```

In my code, I create an object that has a property `RetentionEvent` that has a value of one of the two-letter codes above.  I want to find the Element with the matching Attribute, then return the `fullName` to one text field and the value (wordy description) to another text field.  So far I have the following:

```
// Construct a RecordDisposal object by passing it a valid retention code.
// An exception will be thrown if the code is not valid.
_rd = new RecordDisposal(RetentionCode.Text);
// Load up XML file with description of codes.
XDocument rangeValues = XDocument.Load("DisposalRangeValues.xml");
XElement codeValue = rangeValues.Root.Elements().Single(x => (string)x.Attribute("code") == _rd.DisposalList[0].RetentionEvent);
CodeName.Text = codeValue.Attribute("fullName").Value.ToString();
CodeDescription.Text = codeValue.Value.ToString();
```

The query is a straight mod of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159411/linq-to-xml-trying-to-select-a-list-of-elements-by-the-value-of-their-attribut) code (I think), however I'm getting a couple of errors I don't understand: *"A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause"* (I thought that's what the `ToList()` was for), and *"The type of the expression in the select clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Select'."*  Unfortunately, I don't understand Linq well enough to troubleshoot this, and "Help on this error" provides nothing useful.

What have I done incorrectly?  Also, I'm suspicious that the `ToList()` function is going to return something that doesn't render well in the `ToString()` function, but I was waiting to figure out the other stuff before fooling with that.  If anyone has a suggestion, please offer it.

EDIT: Modified code to use Single based on recommendation below.  Discovered that `rangeValues` is loading all of `<root>` as a single node.

EDIT2: Figured it out.  Modified code to use `rangeValues.Root.Elements()` instead.  Updated code above to reflect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reformatted slightly, you're code looks like this:

```
XElement codeValue =
    from fullName
    in rangeValues.Elements()
                  .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("code") == _rd.DisposalList[0].RetentionEvent)
                  .ToList();
    // select ???
```

So the `ToList()` is applied to the `in` portion of your query, but you're missing a `select` statement.

Actually, since you're looking to return a single `XElement`, you probably want something like this, which selects the only element in the collection that matches the clause specified in `Single()`:

```
XElement codeValue =
    (from fullName in rangeValues.Elements()
     where (string)fullName.Attribute("code") == _rd.DisposalList[0].RetentionEvent
     select fullName).Single();
```

Alternate syntax (the above is query syntax, the following is called method syntax):

```
XElement codeValue =
    rangeValues.Elements().Single(x => (string)x.Attribute("code") == _rd.DisposalList[0].RetentionEvent);
```

If there might not be a match, or could be more than one, you'll want to research `SingleOrDefault()`, `First()`, and `FirstOrDefault()` too.

Comment: I like the `Single()` method, and as you suspect, don't want what `SingleOrDefault()` or either of the others would provide.  However, I'm getting an exception thrown saying _"Sequence contains no matching element"_ when I know it does.  Well, at least I know the value is represented.  Whether or not the XML is loading and parsing correctly is another thing.

Comment: Got it.  Needed to use `rangeValues.Root.Elements()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.ToList()` call is correct, but the syntax for the LINQ query is incorrect.

Try this:

```
List<XElement> fullnames = (from fullName in rangeValues.Elements()
                            where fullName.Attribute("code") == _rd.DisposalList[0].RetentionEvent
                            select fullName).ToList();
```

Comment: This is good, but the `Single()` method worked better in my case.